# Table Cloth/Sheet Ghost

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I’m a beginner and don’t know very much about cloth simulations yet. I’m trying to make a little animation of a cloth falling onto a table and then a sphere comes into frame and flies around the table before eventually going under the table and coming up through the table. When it comes up through the table, I want the cloth to now be draped over the sphere, like a sheet ghost. When I do this, the sphere lifts the cloth slightly before just breaking right through it. Is there a way for the cloth to move with the sphere when the sphere comes up through the table??

Comment: it depends on your settings and how quick the movement is. Have you applied the scale to the objects (Ctrl+A > Scale in *Object* mode)?

Comment: please share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/